# Why can't I define a function as an argument when calling another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know functions can be passed around as arguments in Python, but I don't get why I can't do this:

```
>>> def foo(bar): return bar()
... 
>>> foo(def a(): return 'hello')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo(def a(): return 'hello')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when this is perfectly valid:

```
>>> def foo(bar): return bar()
... 
>>> def a(): return 'hello'
... 
>>> foo(a)
'hello'
```

Comment: Because that's what the language syntax says. A [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) is a compound statement, it can't be a function argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def` is a statement. If you want an anonymous function then use a `lambda` expression.

```
foo(lambda: 'hello')
```

Comment: To anticipate further curiosity from the OP, it's worth noting that the range of functions you can create in a lambda is limited.  It's a feature that you can't shove complicated multi-line code into an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `def` for that. For the object representation of a function, you can use a `lambda`.

```
foo(lambda a: 'hello')
```

Or you can use the name of a function as your second example shows.